# dc.js: multiple dimension filters

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am new to dc.js. And I am trying to use it to filter my dataset by multiple conditions. I could use the following code to filter by one condition(type).

```
var psv = d3.dsvFormat("|");
var experiments = psv.parse("time|userId|type|version\n" + data);
var ndx = crossfilter(experiments);
var typeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["type"]});
var result = typeDim.filter(targetType).top(GLOBAL.MAX_FEEDBACK_COUNT);
```

How could I apply another dimension filter condition to the `result`? Like filtering by `userId`? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One frequent cause of confusion: `.filter` does not return the filtered data. It applies a filter to the dimension, which is stateful. Then `dimension.top()` and `group.all()` are the functions which retrieve raw and aggregated data from the crossfilter.

If you want to apply another filter, you'll usually create another dimension for that, e.g. one keyed on `userId`. Then the crossfilter instance will be filtered on both filters.

Beware, though: a crossfilter group (where you usually read aggregated data) [does not observe its own dimension's filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters). Confusingly, dimension.top [**does** observe this dimension's filter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_top).